# Add Dictionary to NSMutableArray of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

I have an `NSMutableArray` called `myMutbaleArray` that looks like this when I log it

```
2015-12-08 17:04:21.679 APP[3342:573379] (
{
  id = 19;
  "num_test" = 100000;
  url = "http://fsad.com";
},
{
  id = 20;
  "num_test" = 100001;
  url = "http://teeeet.com";
}
)
```

And I want to add an object that looks like this

```
{
  id = 21;
  "num" = 100002;
  url = "http://example.com";
}
```

So I am trying this

```
[myMutbaleArray addObject:@{ @"id":@"23",@"num_test":@"100000", @"url":mainDict[@"website_url"],@"website_name":@"website"}];
```

But when I do this I get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I initialize the array like this

```
@interface {
NSMutableArray *socailArray;
}
//inside connectionDidFinishLoading
socailArray = [dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"];
```

Why can I add another dictionary to the MutableArray?

Thanks

Comment: In addition to my answer; please post the code with which the array is initialised (where `myMutableArray` is assigned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see this, your array is actually not a mutable array. Here is the hint:

```
-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The object is of type `__NSCFArray`, which is an internal counterpart of `NSArray`.

Even if you declare your variable as `NSMutableArray` the pointer can point to an object of any type (event for example `NSRegularExpression`). Important is, how it is created.

This happens to most people if they serialise an array either using `NSUserDefaults`, `NSJSONSerialization` or what ever.

The key is to create a mutable copy when the array gets deserialised using

`-[NSArray mutableCopy]`

Note that this is *not* deep-copy. This means an array contained in the root array will not be mutable copied and needs to be replaced separately.

Deep copying can be achieved using this:

```
// array
NSArray *originalArray = @[@"a", @"b", @[@1, @2]];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = (NSMutableArray *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFArrayRef)originalArray, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);

// dictionary
NSDictionary *originalDictionary = @{@"a": @"b", @"c": @[@{@"abc": @123}]};
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDictionaryRef)originalDictionary, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

Comment: I aded how I init the array in the quesiton

Comment: That does not help. This only shows, that (and how) you reference an object __whithin__ another. The object is actually *created* where `dataDict` is created (or its parent object, if there is one)

Comment: NSArray *tempMyArray = [dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"]; myMutableArry = [tempSocailArray mutableCopy];

Comment: So you already used `mutableCopy`? Hmm... Please edit your question. This again and explain your core problem, I don't think we'll find an answer like this

Answer (score 0):

You should change init to:

```
//inside connectionDidFinishLoading
 socailArray  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"]];
```

Because: `[dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"]` is a `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

With `socailArray = [dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"];`, the type of `[dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"]` is `NSArray`, so it auto cast `socailArray` into `NSArray`, that's why you can not insert thing into this.

To avoid this, you must be hold `socailArray` as `NSMutableArray` using:
`socailArray = [[dataDict valueForKey:@"socail"] mutableCopy];`

Hope this could help.